# How to get exactly Eclipse Editor kind of Tool Tip in RCP/SWT Table cell

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, rcp

I want to get Exactly eclipse editor kind highly customized tooltip like below-

[image]

I used eclipse provided snippets of customized Tooltips but none of them were so highly improvised performance and easy to use.
How to reuse these Tooltips , any example would help.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but did you have a look at the Eclipse source?

Comment: I found out something AbstractReusableInformationControlCreator.. trying to implement it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to extend `org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip`

and override

```
protected abstract Composite createToolTipContentArea(Event event,
            Composite parent);
```

you can add `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser` and set formatted content and add required controls.

Comment: I guess, using a `Browser` is overkill (and will not work on every platform). A `StyledText` should be sufficient.

Comment: I think, as long as eclipse IDE is supported on the platform, browser should also work.

Comment: For example, on common Linux systems there are problems with `Browser`. It can work, but often requires the user to install certain additional packages. Hence, you better should offer a fall-back without `Browser`. Otherwise users easily are frustrated. They will blame your application, not SWT or the packages.

Comment: I see there will issues with browser if you are invoking very complex web page...i think here he just needs to set few lines of formatted html text. if StyledText is used, you need to set Text Styles programmatically.

Comment: I used API's of AbstractInformationControl and IInformationControlExtension2 like these to achieve the one.. Agreed that Browser is as well one easy solution. Linux do have some issue with SWT.BROWSER but eclipse does provide differen plugins of browser for Linux version, so that helped

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhary: can you provide one example of protected abstract Composite createToolTipContentArea in SWT table cell?