# How to make Custom ToolTip Same as Eclipse Tooltip?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, tooltip, eclipse-rcp

Basic function of Eclipse Tool tip:
when mouse hover on to text of code then Tool-tip open then when mouse hover Tool-tip is focus move to opened Tool-tip Scroll-bar is visible.

I have attached Tool-tip screen-shoot.

Tooltipopen mouse on the text:

[image: Tooltipopen mouse on the text]

Scroll Bar is visible when mouse hover to tooltip:

[image: Scroll Bar is visible when mouse hover to tooltip]

Now I want to make tool-tip As same like Eclipse Tool-tip.

I want this tool-tip implement into SWT table Cell tool-tip.When Mouse cursor hover to table Cell then open tool-tip then mouse move/hover to that Tool-tip then Scroll-bar visible.
I have done done many googling then make is  I have tried to make Tool-tip but i can not able to make same like eclipse tool-tip.

```
public static void generateTooltip(final TableCursor tableCursor) {         
    final Listener labelListener = new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            label = (Text) event.widget;
            tip = label.getShell();
            switch (event.type) 
            {
            case SWT.MouseDown:
                label.setFocus();
                break;
            case SWT.MouseExit:                     
                if(!tip.isFocusControl())
                {
                    tip.dispose();
                }
                break;
            case SWT.MouseHover:    
                label.setFocus();
                break;
            case SWT.FocusOut:  
                tip.dispose();
                break;
             case SWT.MouseEnter:
              label.setFocus();
              break;
            }

        }
    };
    Listener tableListener = new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {              
            switch (event.type) {               
            case SWT.Dispose: {
                if (tip == null)
                    break;
                tip.dispose();
                tip = null;
                label = null;
                break;
            }

            case SWT.MouseExit: {

                if(tip != null && !tip.isDisposed())
                {
                    if(!tip.isFocusControl())
                    {
                        tip.dispose();  
                    }
                }       
            }

            case SWT.MouseHover: {
                //for F1 pressed key focus.
                 TableItem item = tableCursor.getRow();
                if (item != null) 
                {

                if(tip != null && !tip.isDisposed()  )
                {
                    if(!tip.isFocusControl()){
                        tip.close();
                          tip.dispose();    
                    }                       
                }           
                if(tableCursor.getRow().getText(tableCursor.getColumn()).equals(""))
                {
                    return;
                }
                    tip = new Shell(tableCursor.getShell(), SWT.ON_TOP| SWT.TOOL);
                    tip.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
                    tip.layout(true, true);
                    tip.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(255, 250, 205));
                    ScrolledComposite scroll = new ScrolledComposite(tip,SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
                    GridData gd_scrolledComposite = new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1);
                    scroll.setLayoutData(gd_scrolledComposite);
                    scroll.setExpandHorizontal(true);
                    scroll.setExpandVertical(true);
                    scroll.setMinSize(item.getBounds().width,item.getBounds().height);
                    Composite compo = new Composite(scroll, SWT.RESIZE);
                    compo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL,true, true, 1, 1));
                    compo.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
                    compo.layout(true);
                    scroll.setContent(compo);                                               
                    label = new Text(compo, SWT.RESIZE | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY);

                    GridData gd_lblNewLabel_2 = new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1);
                    gd_lblNewLabel_2.widthHint = 251;
                    gd_lblNewLabel_2.heightHint = 75;
                    label.setLayoutData(gd_lblNewLabel_2);
                    label.setText(tableCursor.getRow().getText( tableCursor.getColumn()));

                    Label lblNewLabel_1 = new Label(tip, SWT.NONE);
                    GridData gd_lblNewLabel_1 = new GridData(SWT.LEFT,SWT.RIGHT, true, true, 1, 1);                 
                    lblNewLabel_1.setLayoutData(gd_lblNewLabel_1);  
                    lblNewLabel_1.setText("Press F1 to focus");
                    lblNewLabel_1.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(255, 250, 205));

                    Label saveTextLabel = new Label(tip, SWT.NONE);
                    GridData gd_savetext = new GridData(SWT.LEFT,SWT.RIGHT, true, true, 1, 1);
                    saveTextLabel.setLayoutData(gd_savetext);
                    saveTextLabel.setText("Press F3 to Save");
                    saveTextLabel.setVisible(false);
                    saveTextLabel.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(255, 250, 205));

                    label.addListener(SWT.MouseHover, labelListener);
                    label.addListener(SWT.MouseExit, labelListener);
                    label.addListener(SWT.MouseEnter, labelListener);

                    label.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(255,250, 205));
                    Rectangle rect = item.getBounds();
                    Point pt = tableCursor.toDisplay(rect.x, rect.y);
                    tip.setBounds(pt.x - rect.x, pt.y - rect.y  + tableCursor.getSize().y, rect.width,  rect.height);
                    tip.setVisible(true);                       
                    tip.pack(true);
                    setFocusTooltip = 0;

                }
                break;
             }      

            case SWT.Selection: {
                if (tip == null)
                    break;

                if(tip != null && !tip.isDisposed()){                   
                    tip.dispose();
                 }
                }
            case SWT.MouseMove: {
                if (tip == null)
                break;

                if(tip != null && !tip.isDisposed() && !tip.isFocusControl())
                {
                      tip.close();
                      tip.dispose();
                }

            }

            }
            if (event.keyCode == SWT.F1) 
            {               
                if (tip != null && !tip.isDisposed()) {
                    label.setFocus();
                     Listener resizelistener = new Listener (){  
                           @Override  
                           public void handleEvent(Event event) {  
                            Text t = (Text)event.widget; 
                            Rectangle r1 = t.getClientArea();  
                            Rectangle r2 = t.computeTrim(r1.x, r1.y, r1.width, r1.height);  
                            Point p = t.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, true);                               
                            if( t.getHorizontalBar() != null )
                            {
                                t.getHorizontalBar().setVisible(r2.width <= p.x);  
                            }
                            if(  t.getVerticalBar() != null)
                            {
                                t.getVerticalBar().setVisible(r2.height <= p.y);  
                            }

                            if (event.type == SWT.Modify){
                                   t.getParent().layout(true);  
                                   t.showSelection();  
                            }  
                            if(event.type == SWT.Verify){

                            }
                            if(event.type == SWT.MouseMove){
                                if(tip != null && !tip.isDisposed() && !tip.isFocusControl())
                                {
                                      tip.close();
                                      tip.dispose();
                                }
                              }                
                           }};  
                           label.addListener(SWT.Resize, resizelistener);  
                           label.addListener(SWT.Modify, resizelistener);
                           label.addListener(SWT.Verify, resizelistener);
                           label.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, resizelistener);
                           setFocusTooltip = 1;                           
                            }                       
            }}
        };      
        tableCursor.addListener(SWT.Dispose, tableListener);
        tableCursor.addListener(SWT.MouseExit, tableListener);
        tableCursor.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, tableListener);
        tableCursor.addListener(SWT.MouseHover, tableListener);
        tableCursor.addListener(SWT.FocusOut, tableListener);
        tableCursor.addListener(SWT.Traverse, tableListener);
        tableCursor.addListener(SWT.Selection, tableListener);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get exactly Eclipse Editor kind of Tool Tip in RCP/SWT Table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776663/how-to-get-exactly-eclipse-editor-kind-of-tool-tip-in-rcp-swt-table-cell)

Comment: @Baz: How to implement in above code? My code only based on SWT.

Comment: Recently the Eclipse EASE project had to do something similar. In the end they duplicated the code out of the JDT to make it work. see https://bugs.eclipse.org/466461 and https://git.eclipse.org/c/ease/org.eclipse.ease.core.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.ease.ui/src/org/eclipse/ease/ui/help/hovers/internal/JavaDocLikeHover.java?id=812d16ce6155962034d6a95cdadcd5fa62d12dcc as a starting point

Comment: @ Jonah Graham : please share me one link for example